# android - ConstraintLayout se mostra diferente do android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Fiz uma tela de login com o ContraintLayout, no editor do android studio aparece com a margem como eu especifiquei, porém no emulador e no dispositivo aparece sem a margem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.LoginActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/actLogin..."
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_...." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actLoginTv..."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/actLogin..." />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etActLoginEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_email"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/actLoginTv..." />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etActLoginPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLength="16"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etActLoginEmail" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnActLoginSignUp"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:onClick="onSignUpClicked"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etActLoginPassword" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnActLoginSignIn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="195dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:onClick="onSignInClicked"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnActLoginSignUp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnActLoginSignUp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnActLoginSignUp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Por que as margens dos botões somem na tela pratica? Alguns ids eu ocultei o nome por questões de segurança

Comment: Qual o formato da imagem que tu está chamando em app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_...."?

Comment: @julianosantos todos os assets que uso no app é SVG

Answer (score 0):

Eu já passei por uma situação semelhante e resolvi simplesmente mudando o formato da imagem que deve ser mostrada no ImageView. Geralmente svg e vetors de forma geral sempre se comportam de forma estrana em ImageView.Entao pegue a mesma imagem no formato png ou jpeg e adicione ao drawable e depois chame no xml da mesma forma que voce chamou o svg.Creio que seja o suficiente pra resolver